# Can you make pie crust from cookie dough?

Tags: baking, pie, dough, cookies, crust

I recently bought several packs of frozen cookie dough, sugar cookie, and I wanted to know if it's possible to reshape them and make a pie crust?  If so what is the technique involved: cooking temperature, ect...

Comment: My suggestion is to bake the cookies, then crumble them for a cookie-crumb crust.

Comment: @Marti i would instinctively think the same - if you use a recipe for something that bakes ~10min (cookies) for pie crusts, the danger that you have a pie pan instead of a pie shell after it baked as long as pie does (~30-60min.) is high....

Answer (score 8):

My recomendation would be to roll out the dough and pat it into the pie-plate and cook it with out any fillings (blind baking) you will probably need to poke holes into the bottom to keep it from bubbling up (docking).  After it is fully cooked pull it out and let it cool.  I would only use no-bake fillings in this, I don't think the cookie crust would react well to baking twice, maybe a french-silk type filling.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe.  It depends on what you expect.

If you expect something flaky and light like a traditional pie crust, you will be disappointed.

However, Jacques Pepin uses cookie dough for open faced fruit tarts on his show.  And cookie dough can be used to make shells for custard based tarts.

You will need to blind bake the shell.

Comment: I had envisioned this would be more like a graham-cracker style pie shell. Yum.

Answer (score 5):

Should work fine as a crust for a pie that uses a pre-baked crust. Just roll it out like a giant cookie, put it in a pie pan, and bake like a cookie.

I have no idea what would happen if you tried it with a pie that bakes the crust at the same time as the filling though. I don't think cookie dough would hold up that well on top, it would probably just make a mess as cookies usually have a significantly shorter baking time than pies; also cookie dough has a lot more fat than a crust so it would probably just melt into the filling.

I'd try it with a pumpkin pie (or another pie that has no top crust) and see what happens. It might not work that well but the result would probably still be edible.

Comment: You don't even need to roll it out -- use the coarse side of a box grater to turn it into shreds, then pack that into the pie pan.  It might not give pretty crimped edges, but saves time when it's still frozen hard.

Comment: @Joe: A box grater solves all sorts of problems :) I doubt cookie dough would hold the crimping anyway, it is usually way too soft and melty for that.

Answer (score 3):

While I've never tried this, it should be pretty straightforward.  You'll want to treat this as if it's a frozen pre-formed pie crust and bake it separately from the filling for the best results.  That way you can just shape the dough in the pie pan and follow the baking directions in the package.  A couple of things to note though:

1- cookies puff up a little when you bake them.  This normally doesn't happen to pie crusts, so you'll have to consider that when filling your pie.  Perhaps some pie weights can help in this situation.

2- frozen doughs can be tricky to rework.  If you're making a runny variety of pie this may not be your best bet.  If your goal is to have a pie with a sugar cookie crust you might consider making it from scratch as it may roll more easily and prevent leaks in your pie.  If what you are looking for is convenience, I'd say make the cookie dough into cookies and go buy a pre-formed pie crust.

Answer (score 2):

This is certainly possible in general -- though I've never tried using pre-made cookie dough.  You can certainly search online and find all sorts of recipes with pies with cookie crusts, and sugar cookie is the probably the most common.  (Or, it's at least the most common that's actually baked whole, as opposed to baked and then crumbled to make a sort of "crumb" crust.)

Many people have mentioned blind baking to be necessary; I've seen recipes for both ways.  It really depends on the consistency of the crust and the type of filling.  I've definitely made an apple pie multiple times with a sugar-cookie crust that baked along with the filling, and frankly I would advise against pre-baking the crust in that case, since cookie dough often tends to bake and brown more quickly than typical pie crust.  It's one of the few pies I almost always need a "pie shield" to prevent excessive crust browning on the outside.  On the other hand, many other recipes recommend blind baking the crust first, which probably produces a slightly crisper result on the bottom.  (The crust for the apple pie I mentioned tends to be cookie-like on the edges and top, but more cake-like on the bottom presumably due to moisture.)

I've also found a lot of success in putting cookie dough on top, though I'd recommend against a full "double-crust," since that would seem overwhelming in terms of sugar and richness.  But a lattice crust could potentially work well (as long as the dough is fairly firm), or you could also pre-bake individual small sugar cookies and then float them on top of the filling.  Again, the optimal way to do this will depend on the consistency of the dough and how fast it bakes.

Personally, I actually enjoy making pies with cookie dough crusts a lot more, because there's not all that worry about getting the exact consistency to get the perfect flakiness, etc.  Usually with cookie dough crusts, it doesn't matter if you screw up and need to roll it out again -- just make it into a ball and do it again.  It's not going to risk toughening it significantly or ruining the texture as with a standard pie crust.  And if you're constructing a lattice or whatever and things break, no big deal: just press them together or re-roll.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why not I mean its the same as using it for cherry pie bars . Just pat dough for  the bottom of pie Pan or cake pan bake it for about 15 minutes add pie filling (use 2 pie filling cans if using 9 X 13 cake pan ) and add pieces of cookie dough like you would crumbles evenly on top and bake for about an hour watch so it doesn't brown  too quick at 350 degrees oven..cool slightly and serve with whipped topping..

Answer (score 0):

Spray pie plate, slice cookie dough about 1/2 inch, place on bottom and around sides just till toudhing, let soften, then press all together.  Can anyone tell at what temperature to bake and for how long?  All I remember is don't bake for too long till dough is crunchy.

Comment: Hello and welcome - in general, try to make sure that you're not asking additional questions within your answer.  You can request clarifications to other answers or the original question using comments, but the best answers are usually definitive.

Answer (score 0):

My great-grandmother's apple pie recipe used a sugar-cookie dough for the crust. It's very doable.

Comment: Can you tell us more about your great-grandmother's method? Did she pat the dough into the pan? Did she blind bake it?

Comment: Alas, she passed on before I was old enough to learn it. My mother saved the recipe, but claimed it was never "right," and we've retired it as incorrectly recorded. I do know it was made with oil, not butter, and was rolled out.

Answer (score 0):

As a prebaked pie crust should work just fine, press the dough into a pie plate. If you don't want it to sag too much from fat melting as it is being baked, freeze it before you bake (or at least refrigerate it). I have made such crusts - what I haven't done is used the prebaked crust for a pie with filling that needs a longer term bake.  If I was going to do that I would probably freeze the baked prebaked pie crust before I filled it, just to slow down any further baking of the crust.

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to remember the recipes where a cookie crust is best and I'm remembering only quickly-cooked fillings and cold fillings.

If you use raw dough and a long cooked filling (up to about 1 hour), the crust will be ruined due to burning.

This is how I did it: First, bake the cookie dough as a pie shell. Second, add pudding pie fillings or other fillings (fried apples, stove topped berry, ...) to it. Third, top with other toppings, such as meringue, whipped toppings, or ice cream.

Answer (score 0):

I've used commercial, pre-made sugar cookie dough for apple pies. It is to die for! Add a little flour to the dough, a scant quarter cup, and you will find it rolls out easier while keeping the taste. Reserve some of the dough. Bake the pie without a top layer, then about halfway through add some raw, cut-out cookies made from the reserved dough to serve as the top crust. I find it doesn't freeze well, but it is delicious!

Comment: This is an interesting technique! But including some key details like baking time and temperature would be a big improvement.